# Storing promise value into variable not resolving nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

### so I've been struggling with this problem for a little while now and I need some help. So first I have an api call that looks like this:

```
async function getJoke() {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/random",
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "**********",
        "accept": "application/json"
      }
    })

    return res.data.value

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

### Then I have my index where I am calling this function and trying to assign the return value to a variable to be used:

```
async function tellJoke() {
    let joke = await getJoke()
    return joke
}

const data = tellJoke()
console.log(data)
```

### console.log(data) returns a pending promise and not the return value as expected, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try to `await` on calling it. like this `const data = await tellJoke();`

Comment: @ZeyadEtman `await` can only be used in `async function`s. The code is probably running synchronously.

Comment: Yes I know, I mean that he change it, and this solution requires async function wrapper, so he create it where he want.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `async function`s return a promise that resolves to their return value. You can't write synchronous code that `await`s promises.

You can, however, wrap your code in an async IIFE, like so:

```js
async function tellJoke() {
    let joke = await getJoke()
    return joke
}

;(async function (){

const data = await tellJoke()
console.log(data)

})();
```

Or you can use `Promise.prototype.then`. `then` executes a specified callback once the promise resolves.

```js
async function tellJoke() {
    let joke = await getJoke()
    return joke
}

tellJoke().then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function returns a `Promise`, so you need to wait for the `tellJoke()` function.

If you are in an `async` function you need only to `const data = await tellJoke()`, otherwise you should use promise chain:

```
tellJoke()
 .then(joke => console.log(joke))
 .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions return Promises. `async` and `await` are easy-to-use syntax for promise handling. So when you call an async function from an non-async function you need to treat it as a promise.

Your last two lines should be:

```
tellJoke()
.then ( function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        })
.catch ( function (error) {
          console.error (error);
       })
```

You can abbreviate this

```
tellJoke()
.then ( console.log )
.catch ( console.error )
```